# Regex to match multiple delimiters

Tags: regex

I have something like this

```
START SOMETEXT1 DELIMITER START SOMETEXT2 DELIMITER START SOMETEXT3 DELIMITER
```

I want to match `SOMETEXT1`, `SOMETEXT2` and `SOMETEXT3` and I have multiple delimiters, say `DELIMITER1`, `DELIMITER2` and `DELIMITER3`.

I can't figure out how to construct a regex that matches `DELIMITER1`, `DELIMITER2` or `DELIMITER3` whichever comes first.

Let's say `START(.*?)(DELIMITER1|DELIMITER2|DELIMITER3)` will match

```
START SOMETEXT1 DELIMITER2 START SOMETEXT2 DELIMITER1
```

Instead of `START SOMETEXT1 DELIMITER2` because it tries to match the delimiters in the given order.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get the point of your question. Having "(DELIMITER1|DELIMITER2|DELIMITER3)" in your regexp matches anything between "START" and one of the delimiters, no matter which. A site I like for testing regexps is: http://regexpal.com/ .

Comment: `START(.*?)(DELIMITER1|DELIMITER2|DELIMITER3)` is the correct answer, the (.*?) indicates a lazy match which will match as few characters as possible before matching any of your three delimiters. What are your delimeters, and are you escaping them correctly?

Comment: What happens is that it tries to find DELIMITER1 first because it is the first option in the regex and eventually it will find at some point in the text skipping DELIMITER2 and DELIMITER3

Comment: What regex library are you using and what are your delimeters. You're claiming that if you switch it to `START(.*?)(DELIMITER2|DELIMITER1|DELIMITER3)` it starts working as expected?

Comment: @DavidBenko - Your regex should work as it is: http://www.rubular.com/r/kGPx6XyVWN

Comment: @user1428799 yeah I just figured out one of my delimiters was messing up the search lol thanks